# Edit text should allow text if a. alphabet +number b. alphabet +special character c. alphabet only

Tags: android, regex, android-edittext

I am trying to generate a regular expression in Android which can satisfy following conditions:
Edit text can accept:

1. Alphabet only
2. Combination of Alphabet  and number
3. Combination of Alphabet  and special character

Should not accept:
a. Only Number
b. Only Special character

I tried alot but still, i didn't get any meaningful link. Please try to save my day.

I tried with regular expression (?!^\d+$)^.+$") which only valid alphanumric requirement. I am looking for such regular expression which fullfil my requirement.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having exactly?

Comment: have you tried using editText text listener? please update the question with what you have tried so far

Comment: I have check with reg exp. (?!^\d+$)^.+$") . But it works for alpha numric combination. I didnt get any reg exp which fulfill my requirement.

Comment: if have updated my answer.. check..

Comment: public static boolean isTextProper(String pSubjectName) {
        if (pSubjectName != null && pSubjectName.matches(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*")) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really simple bro... just **clear EditText if the text inside it doesn't have an alphabet** .. *as you have said* ...

> Should not accept **a. Only Number b**. **Only Special character**

```
TextWatcher mTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        boolean atleastOneAlpha = s.toString().matches(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*");

        if (!atleastOneAlpha) {
            editText.setText("");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};

mTargetEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
```

Comment: Thanks bro, It is working. I agreed it so simple but still i didnt find solution.